# ASMX web service shared between projects

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have an ASMX web service which is being called using Soap protocol. The service is using request / response types from one of our shared projects.

The project that consumes this service is also using the shared project. Now, I want that the reference that's been used in the project for that service should reuse the types being used in the shared project.

If that is not possible then can we inherit the service from an interface and then the wsdl tool can generate the implementation of the interface by inheriting from required classes?

Will WCF be an alternative?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029300/webreferences-sharing-classes?

Comment: The issue mentioned is different as here I want to reuse the types in existing project but not service. One of the alternative is to create my own generator as it only call invoke and typecast it to same type. We can use interface which will be used at both services.